# Can subscript of sequence be negative?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, definition

Can subscript of sequence be negative? It implies that subscript in integer, so it can be negative? From analysis tao.

[image]

Comment: Depends how things are defined, but it is common to have sequences indexed by all integers.

Comment: yeah i know it is interger,  so it can be negative?

Comment: For example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series

Comment: ohhhh thanks thanks thanks

Comment: subscripts can be anything you define them to be, integers, rationals, reals, complex numbers with some property , fruits, matrices etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequences in this definition all have a first element, which is $m$.  Whether $m$ is positive, negative, or zero really does not change things.  You could define a new index offset by $m$ which would start at $0$.  The sequence is still single ended.

One can also imagine sequences that go on infinitely in both directions like the integers.  That is different. The Laurent series is one such that is used.  There are a number of conventions for Fourier series, but one can have the frequencies be all integer multiples of some fundamental.